# set shortcut to move between windows in reverse

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, vim

version: Ubuntu 18.04

i want to move between windows and work spaces in a "vim-like" way.

I set ctrl+alt u/d to move up/down work spaces, and changed alt tab (switch between windows -->) to ctrl+alt+l. And I want to move in reverse order (<--) using ctrl+alt+h.

The documentation suggests this is done using the shift key: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-windows-switching.html.en.

But I cannot see it listed in the settings where i can change it. Under keyboard shortcuts i see only "switch windows" (where i easily changed it from alt tab to ctrl+alt+l) but not switch windows in reverse order.

How can i set the shortcut to switch windows in reverse order?

Comment: This depends on the desktop environment and window manager. We have no idea what desktop environment you use, although there is a strong suspicion it will be the standard Ubuntu desktop with Gnome Shell. *Edit* your question and add system specs: Ubuntu version and desktop environment.

Comment: sorry, it slipped my mind: ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With following commands, you can bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>L/H</kbd> to directly switch windows forward and backward. The commands given preserve the default bindings as well:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-windows "['<Alt>Escape', '<Control><Alt>l']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-windows-backward "['<Shift><Alt>Escape','<Control><Alt>h']"
```

Alternatively, you could switch forward and backwards in the window popup with the commands.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows "['<Control><Alt>l']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows-backward "['<Control><Alt>h']"
```

Depending on the Ubuntu version, these keys may already be bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, so you could add `<Alt>Tab` or `<Shift><Alt>Tab`.

The latter binding can be set in "Settings", "Keyboard", but that interface allows to set only one binding at a time.

To undo your changes and return these settings to default, replace `set`  by `reset` and remove the last argument.

Comment: thanks a lot for this. I'm trying to add it using the interface in settings:

name: Switch windows backward /

command: switch-windows-backward /

shortcut: [i just enter the keys and it records them] /

i guess i have the command wrong?

Comment: My bad: arguments in commands should be quoted: corrected this.

Comment: excellent, it works!, cheers

Comment: also works for ubuntu 20.04! :)